# Multiple TCP to Serial connections python attempt.

Tags: python, tcp, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

So I'm trying to create a python script that will allow multiple TCP connections from different computers and allow talking over the serial from the TCP client.  Here is what I was playing with

```
import sys
import os
import time
import fileinput
import socket  
import serial
import thread
serialData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600)

import argparse


def on_new_client(clientsocket,addr):
        while True:
            msg = clientsocket.recv(1024) 
            #do some checks and if msg == someWeirdSignal: break:
            print addr, ' >> ', msg
            serialData.write(msg)
            #msg = raw_input('SERVER >> ') 
            #Maybe some code to compute the last digit of PI, play game or 
anything else can go here and when you are done.
            clientsocket.send(msg) 
        clientsocket.close()


def on_Send_client(clientsocket,addr):
        while True:
            x = serialData.readline()
            clientsocket.send(x) 
        clientsocket.close()


s = socket.socket()
host = '' #ip of raspberry pi
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)



serialData.isOpen()

serialData.write("This is a test")




while True:


  c, addr = s.accept()

  thread.start_new_thread(on_new_client,(c,addr))
  #thread.start_new_thread(on_Send_client,(c,addr))

s.close()
```

Right now I can connect with multiple TCP clients and eco their data.  Their data also gets sent out the serial port.  How should I go about buffering the serial data and sending it back out any and all connections that are active? Seems like nothing I look for online can do this correctly and Socat command even fails for multiple connections to serial.